# How is the size of a C array known by the compiler?

Tags: c

Say I have some array ar, I know sizeof(ar); will return the total length of the array in bytes (size of data value type * the total number of array spaces).

If the array name ar is converted to a base pointer address and subscripts are converted to an integer offset by the C compiler, where is the size of the array stored in memory?

Or is it similar to a string where there is some special value that denotes the termination of the array?

Maybe I'm misunderstanding how arrays work in C but I can't work out how the sizeof() function would obtain the size of an array.

Any information would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The size isn't stored anywhere.  The compiler knows what the size of an array is (assuming the actual array is in scope) and can calculate it at compile time when `sizeof array` is used.

When an array is passed to a function and therefore converted to a pointer to its first element, the size is no longer available so the size must also be passed to the function.